# Is there a `USING` clause in SQLAlchemy core?

Tags: mysql, sqlalchemy

I'm using SQLAlchemy on MySQL database. Is there a way I can use MySQL's `USING` clause to join tables?

e.g.

```
SELECT *
FROM
  a JOIN b
    USING(some_id, other_id);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Short answer

No.

### Longer answer

You could write a [compiler extension](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/core/compiler.html) to render the statement, but I don't think it is worth the effort. Explanation below.

In MySQL you don't have to use `USING` to join tables. It's considered syntactic sugar over the more general `ON` construct.

SQLAlchemy does not include handling the special case that the join columns have the same name (main use-case for using `USING`). It always uses the most general approach (`ON`).

As SQLAlchemy will render all `ON` statements for you, and in most cases will infer the join-relationships from your `Table` definitions and thus obviating the need to specify the join condition *at all*, this is not necessarily more work.

### Example

```
t1 = Table('a', metadata,
           Column('id', Integer))
t2 = Table('b', metadata,
           Column('id', Integer),
           Column('fk', Integer, ForeignKey('a.id')))

sel = select([
    t1.c.id,
    t2.c.id,
]).select_from(
    t1.join(t2)  # please note, no ON or USING
)
print sel
```

Will result in

```
SELECT a.id, b.id 
FROM a JOIN b ON a.id = b.fk
```